# Will this plumbing connection to my sink be viable?

Tags: plumbing

I'm trying to understand if this plumbing configuration looks viable. Hoping to get some help on this. I'm not sure if the slope will work.

[image: Sink]

Comment: If you use a spigot end trap adapter instead of a hub end, the p trap could be a little higher and probably not need that upward turn. Also, you could turn the p trap around directly toward the trap arm. Functionality-wise it might not matter, but it would look neater.

Comment: This will probably work fine, but a much simpler arrangement can be purchased for $5 or $10 (if you are in the US) as a kit with only about 4 parts.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Ended up being able to get a piece that connected directly to my sink drain and gave me back the space I needed to get the slope with the p-trap and fewer pieces.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is viable, I probably wouldn't change this just for the sake of it.  But if you're already working on it and want something easier to maintain with fewer parts .... this entire kit is $7 and may be all you need.  You may need an additional compression nut and washer at the wall end, although these kits sometimes come with some extras.

[image]

Addressing the question about slope, if you are referring to the slope of the bend highlighted in yellow that in itself is not a problem.  The trap water level will be where indicated in green, and everything in between will be wet.  Just imagine the whole thing is the trap.  Hopefully it's all very water tight.

Ideally (and if you replace as suggested) the trap resting water will be entirely inside a solid piece with no joints.  In fact, I'll change my advice: for that reason alone you ought to splurge the $7 on the replacement.  Note that a useful element of the suggested replacement is a slip joint that allows you to install at the right level easily.

[image]

Comment: Better as an answer than a comment! ;) +1

Comment: @jay613 - Answer might be improved by addressing slope which is one of the concerns raised by the OP. 1/4" per foot is required. Not sure from the pic that the current setup has that.

Comment: Is that required for the horizontal exit of a trap?  A) I don't think it is, and B) I assumed the slope question pertained to the unnecessary extra elbow that slopes upward after the trap (but can be thought of as part of it) and not to the metal pipe exiting the wall, which I assumed is outside OP's current scope.  I may of course be wrong about all those things.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Ended up being able to get a piece that connected directly to my sink drain and gave me back the space I needed to get the slope with the p-trap and fewer pieces.